Для чего нужно поле payload в messages.send и как его использовать (vk-io)?
В методе messages.send есть поле payload, в который, как сказано в API, нужно передавать JSON объект. Я использую TypeScript вместе с модулем VK-IO, и мне понадобилось давать каждому сообщению в чате, отправленному моим ботом, давать определенный payload. Вот, как я это сделал:
const chat = new Chat(chatId)
await chat.send({
    message: `message`,
    disable_mentions: true,
    keyboard: undefined,
    attachment: attachments,
    payload: {
        testPayload: 'test'
    }
})

Но кода я обрабатываю это сообщение, то PayLoad всегда undefined
if (replyMessage) {
    console.log(message.replyMessage.messagePayload) // undefined
}

Как это реализовать?

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Vk api для чего нужен параметр payload в messages.send
